# How to resolve System.InvalidOperationException using MVC 6 - Same template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET in general and have recently come across this error which I can't find on the web (maybe because of the recent release of MVC 6?)

```
System.InvalidOperationException The following errors occurred with attribute routing information:
```

**Error 1:**

> Attribute routes with the same name 'GetByIdRoute' must have the same
>   template: Action: 'Appname.Web.Controllers.MemberController.GetById' -
>   Template: 'api/Member/{id:int}' Action:
>   'Appname.Web.Controllers.PaymentController.GetById' - Template:
>   'api/Payment/{id:int}' Action:
>   'Appname.Web.Controllers.PlanController.GetById' - Template:
>   'api/Plan/{id:int}'

This gives a code snipper to startup.cs

```
Line 73:  
Line 74:              // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
Line 75:              app.UseMvc(routes =>
Line 76:              {
Line 77:                  routes.MapRoute(
```

with line 75 highlighted

**and this:**

```
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ControllerActionDescriptorBuilder.Build(ApplicationModel application) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.GetCollection() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoute.GetInnerRoute() 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoute..ctor(IRouter target, IActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider actionDescriptorsCollectionProvider, IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRouting.CreateAttributeMegaRoute(IRouter target, IServiceProvider services) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.BuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes) 
at Appname.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory) in ... Startup.cs:line 75
```

Comment: You cannot have different routes with the same name...imagine when generating links by route name, if there are multiple routes with the same name, which one should be chosen?...try having different names like `GetPaymentById`, `GetPlanById` etc.

Comment: As @KiranChalla says, your MapRoutes have the same template name. If you provide the entire `app.UseMvc` statement (starting line 75 to the end of the routes declaration), someone is sure to show you exactly which parts need to change.

Comment: @Daniel: I am facing a similar problem. What was your solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

You can specify route name.

> In Web API, every route has a name. Route names are useful for generating links, so that you can include a link in an HTTP response.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPerson")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var item = this.PeopleRepository.GetById(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            return this.HttpNotFound();
        }

        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
```

By doing that you can have another controller with the same action name (but different route name)

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPurchase")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var item = this.PurchaseRepository.GetById(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            return this.HttpNotFound();
        }

        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = nameof(GetPurchaseById))]
    public IActionResult GetPurchaseById(int id)
    {
        var item = this.PurchaseRepository.GetById(id);

        if (item == null)
        {
            return this.HttpNotFound();
        }

        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
```

so that then in the HttpPost response I can do

```
    return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetPurchaseById), new { Id = res.PurchaseId}, res);
```

This will automatically set the Location header in your response to get the created entity